# Unable to run Gephi 0.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit

Tags: 14.04, java

I know there are some discussions on this topic already, but none seem to work for me.

I have the Java JDK installed:

```
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

When I try to run `./bin/gephi` the splash screen pops up, then it terminates.

If I run `./bin/gephi -h` I get the following output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl$ProxyListener can not access a member of class org.openide.filesystems.$Proxy0 with modifiers "public"
at org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl$ProxyListener.<init>(WeakListenerImpl.java:423)
at org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl.create(WeakListenerImpl.java:164)
at org.openide.util.WeakListeners.create(WeakListeners.java:271)
at org.openide.filesystems.MultiFileObject.<init>(MultiFileObject.java:125)
at org.openide.filesystems.MultiFileObject.<init>(MultiFileObject.java:142)
at org.openide.filesystems.MultiFileSystem.getMultiRoot(MultiFileSystem.java:267)
at org.openide.filesystems.MultiFileSystem.findResource(MultiFileSystem.java:355)
at org.openide.filesystems.FileUtil.getConfigFile(FileUtil.java:2276)
at org.openide.filesystems.FileUtil.getConfigRoot(FileUtil.java:2306)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.CLICoreBridge.usage(CLICoreBridge.java:107)
at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.showHelp(CLIHandler.java:162)
at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.checkHelp(CLIHandler.java:216)
at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.initialize(CLIHandler.java:567)
at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.initialize(CLIHandler.java:383)
at org.netbeans.MainImpl.execute(MainImpl.java:190)
at org.netbeans.MainImpl.main(MainImpl.java:85)
at org.netbeans.Main.main(Main.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl$ProxyListener can not access a member of class org.openide.filesystems.$Proxy0 with modifiers "public"
at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102)
at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(AccessibleObject.java:296)
at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:288)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:412)
at org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl$ProxyListener.<init>(WeakListenerImpl.java:413)
... 16 more
```

I have tried to change the `gephi.conf` file to point to my JDK path. My `JAVA_HOME` path is: `JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_40` - but no luck.

*How should I proceed?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Java 7 instead of Java 8 (uninstall Java 8), *gephi* seems to have some issue with Java 7.

[Source](https://github.com/gephi/gephi/issues/963)

Answer (score 1):

As described on [Gephi - The Open Graph Viz Platform](http://gephi.github.io/users/install/), don't use OpenJDK **:\**

> 1. Update your distribution with the last official JRE packages (update 25+), don’t use OpenJDK.
> 2. After the download completes, unzip and untar the file in a directory.
> 3. Run it by executing `./bin/gephi` script file.

and

> OpenJDK is not supported, be sure to run the official Java 6 version
>   from Oracle’s website.
>
> Gephi may be able to start with OpenJDK but the graph window will fail
>   to load in most cases.

---

Therefore you should use Oracle Java in this case (*Oracle Java 8 doesn't works in my test*)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

If you don't like Oracle Java as your default Java, edit your `gephi.conf` in `gephi/etc`

```
nano gephi/etc/gephi.conf
```

and set `jdkhome`

```
jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have many versions of Java, use this:

```
./gephi --jdkhome /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
```